# Renaming Duplicates in CSV column in sequence by python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, duplicates

I have CSV data with a particular column having duplicate entries say
like a,b,c,a,b,c,v,f,c... I want to replace the values to
a,b,c,a_1,b_1,c_1,v,f,c_2...
I have wrote the below code to find duplicates:-

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

duplicate_names=[]
file='2018_Akola_August.csv'

with open(file, 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
     occurrences = Counter()
     for line in csv.reader(csv_file):
         email = line[3]
         if email in occurrences:
            print(email)
            duplicate_names.append(email)
            occurrences[email] += 1
         else:
            occurrences[email] = 1
```

Also to replace a string in CSV column I wrote code as below but is
not working as desired for two duplicate values.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False, header=0)
#Finds 'a' and replaces it with 'a_1'
df.loc[df['Circle'] == 'a' , 'Circle']= 'a_1'
print(df)
df.to_csv(file)
```

What effect does this statement will have is not clear?

```
 df.loc[df['Circle'] == 'a' , 'Circle'][]= 'a_1'
```

How to go about renaming such duplicates in sequence?

Comment: Kindly include the first few lines of you csv file illustrating your point so we can answer you with code using this sample data.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way in 2 steps:

```
>>> df
  Circle
0      a
1      b
2      c
3      a
4      b
5      c
6      v
7      f
8      c

dups = (df.loc[df['Circle'].duplicated(),'Circle'] + '_' +
        df.groupby('Circle').cumcount().astype(str))

df.loc[dups.notnull(),'Circle'] = dups

>>> df
  Circle
0      a
1      b
2      c
3    a_1
4    b_1
5    c_1
6      v
7      f
8    c_2
```

In answer to your second question, the line:

```
df.loc[df['Circle'] == 'a' , 'Circle']= 'a_1'
```

Will take all values of `Circle` where it is equal to `a` and change it to `a_1`